# Strange InvalidOperationException when updating entity with RIA Services

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I'm working with EF4.1, RIA Services and Silverlight. I'm having a somewhat bizarre problem in an update scenario.

The domain model is quite simple; it deals with **Requests** and **Persons**. They have a 1-to-n relationship. So a Citizen can have multiple Requests although in reality this will never occur since *the app simply does not provide functionality to do so.*

**Request** has a property called 'Urgent', which I change to **true** and then try to save. All goes well until the actual persisting begins via this method:

```
    public void UpdateRequest(Request currentRequest)
    {
        Request original = ChangeSet.GetOriginal(currentRequest);
        try
        {
            ObjectContext.Requests.AttachAsModified(currentRequest, original);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // weirdness here!
        }
    }
```

which is pretty much the standard generated method by RIA Services (except the try/catch handler which I added for debugging purposes.) I then get the following error:

When I check the ChangeSet, there are *no* Requests to be added, so I'm sure I didn't add it by accident.

```
An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.
```

i don't understand this... There are literally **no** added objects in the ObjectStateManager, the ChangeSet has **no** added objects; where the hell is this coming from?  I tracked which properties are being changed, so I'm sure the key is not overwritten, nor is it being added or some other funkyness.

Can anyone shed some light here? Driving me crazy for several days so far...

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of you adding it elsewhere. Is there code that would have possibly loaded the entity prior to this update method executing? Another query executing in the same roundtrip?

Comment: What do you see in CallStack window? Can't you track persist operation call?

Comment: As mentioned by Anthony Pegram you can't attach model once you loaded the entity with the same key. The changes must be applied to attached entity.

Comment: Thats what I did, I loaded the entity with the given key, changed 1 property and tried to save. The **UpdateRequest** method is the one generated by RIA Service so that one *should* work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it using the following logic, basically we're checking if the entity is attached already. If it is, we don't re-attach it but just update the values. Otherwise, we attach it.

```
        ObjectStateEntry entry;
        // Track whether we need to perform an attach
        bool attach;
        if (ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(ObjectContext.CreateEntityKey("Requests", currentRequest), out entry))
        {
            // Re-attach if necessary
            attach = entry.State == EntityState.Detached;
        }
        else
        {
            // Attach for the first time
            attach = true;
        }
        if (attach)
        {
            ObjectContext.DocumentRequests.AttachAsModified(currentRequest, original);
        }
        else
        {
            ObjectContext.Requests.ApplyCurrentValues(currentRequest);
        }
```